# Unable to connect to Analysis Service Server from Excel, Visual Studio and PowerBI

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-studio, sql-server, microsoft-powerbi

Within our domain we have an analysis service server running with cubes. When trying to retrieve this data using Excel (Get data from Analysis Service), Visual Studio (using source control explorer) and PowerBI (Get data from Analysis Service), we get an error:

> Unable to connect. An error has occurred while trying to connect. Details: Cannot access the dataset. Please contact the owner of the dataset.

This is translated, so I hope the error description is clear. We will get a similar error in Visual Studio. We can access the cubes directly from SQL Server Management Studios, but they are not accessible by end users using their applications.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem lies here (is it on application level, SQL SMS or network)?

Comment: Tricky Issues, @Hoxus, and quite vaguely described by these generic descriptions. Can you please try to apply some of the troubleshooting tips that appear [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Data-Source-published-in-Power-BI-Service-deleted-PBI-Desktop/idi-p/298151/page/2)?

Comment: @DOBRESCU_Mihai, I am not sure what information I can provide besides this. End users are able to connect to the SSAS data source using their local desktop. However when trying to access the SSAS server while on their VDI virtual environment, they are unable to.

Comment: Probably some Log Files would help, @Hoxus. But these Issues appear to be Intensively Tricky. This is why we have pointed you to that experience where you may find some clues.

Comment: Thank you, I am checking the thread out now. Would I need to check log files of SQL Server Management Studios or of the applications we use to try to connect to the data source?

Comment: The most comprehensive answer would obviously be: _both_. We would take them one by one and see what is happening in each instance. For instance, check _PowerBI_'s interaction with the _SSMS_ and see what is going on. Difficult Task.